# Why controller has to call interface on use cases in Clean Architecture

Tags: clean-architecture

In Robert Martin's clean architecture book, I appears the Controller has to call an interface to the UseCase. However, since all dependencies point inward, meaning the Adapter layer has a dependency on the Application layer, then why then need for an interface? I should be able to new up the Usecase directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending of the size and the complexity of ur project it would be perfectly fine to simply create the use case interactor with new in the controller and use the implementation directly.

However there are a few advantages of using interfaces (input ports):

- Testing: in case u want to unit test ur controller code an interface would allow u to mock away the use case interactor
- Dependencies: in case ur use case interactor has dependencies to domain services or repositories then u want to "wire those up" in ur "main component" and just pass the use case interactor via interface (input port) to the controller

For a more in depth discussion on controllers and presenters pls have a look at my blog post: http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Controller-Presenter/